# no known conversion from 'std::shared_ptr<int>' to 'int *' for 1st argument

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

when operating smart pointers, something confused me.

Hers is the error message

```
no known conversion from 'std::shared_ptr<int>' to 'int *' for 1st argument
```

and here's the code I ran

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class test {
public:
  int x_;
  test(int *x) {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  auto x = std::make_shared<int>(5);
  std::shared_ptr<test> t = std::make_shared<test>(x);
}
```

I think this error came from the different types of pointers.
And compilation can succeed when changing

```
std::shared_ptr<test> t = std::make_shared<test>(x);
```

into

```
std::shared_ptr<test> t = std::make_shared<test>(&(*x));
```

But this operation `&(*)`, in my opinion, looks weird. I'm not sure that is a common usage when people program.

Is there any suggestion for this question?
Thanks.

Comment: My go to smart pointer is `std::unique_ptr`.  The `std::shared_ptr` is the one I use a the pointer-of-last-resort, because a shared_ptr has federated ownership which (assuming it doesn't hold a `const` type) is tantamount to a **mutable global**.  Which makes the code harder to reason about, and susceptible to spooky action at a distance bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`x.get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get).

It's not implicitly convertible because that would make it too easy to make mistakes, like creating another shared_ptr from the same raw pointer without proper sharing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try it in my project.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to pass `std::shared_ptr<int>` to a constructor accepting `int *`. There is no implicit conversion for it.

You have two choices -

1. change to `std::shared_ptr<test> t = std::make_shared<test>(x.get());`
2. or change the constructor to `test(std::shared_ptr<int> x) {}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try it in my project.